# Spring boot not resolving custom properties from application.properties during integration tests

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-test

My Spring Boot test configuration is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {TestEnd2EndIntegrationConfiguration.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(Profiles.TEST)//=="test"
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractEnd2EndIntegrationTest {

}
```

Then from `application-test.properties` I have the following **custom** properties:

```
database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
database.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
database.hibernate.logSqlInfo=true
```

Which I use as follows:

```
@Value("${database.hibernate.dialect}")
private String hibernateDialect;
```

However, the custom properties are not resolved and I get exceptions such as:

```
com.bignibou.it.controller.signup.SignupRestControllerTest > shouldRejectUnavailableEmailAddress FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException
```

**edit**:

Here is my gradle configuration:

```
 sourceSets {

        main {
            output.resourcesDir = output.classesDir
        }

        integrationTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/it/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/it/resources', 'src/main/resources']
            compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
            runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
        }
    }

   task integrationTest(type: Test) {
        description "Run the integration tests."
        testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
        reports.html.destination = file("$reports.html.destination/integration")
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("$reports.junitXml.destination/integration")
    }
```

**edit 2**:

When I run the tests from the IDE (intellij), I get a different error:

```
ava:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 36 more

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:183)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:276)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:278)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$ConfigurationPropertySources cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileEnvironmentPostProcessor$ConfigurationPropertySources
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileEnvironmentPostProcessor$ConfigurationPropertySources.finishAndRelocate(ConfigFileEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:528)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileEnvironmentPostProcessor$PropertySourceOrderingPostProcessor.reorderSources(ConfigFileEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileEnvironmentPostProcessor$PropertySourceOrderingPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigFileEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:235)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:673)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 36 more
```

**edit 3**:

Here is the **detailed cause** from the Gradle integrationTest

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [${database.hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}] as strategy [org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.processProperties(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:925)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:840)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
```

**edit 4**: from a debug within: `EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl`:

```
configurationValues = {HashMap@4101}  size = 14
 0 = {HashMap$Node@4092} "hibernate.format_sql" -> "${database.hibernate.logSqlInfo}"
 1 = {HashMap$Node@4096} "hibernate.use_sql_comments" -> "${database.hibernate.logSqlInfo}"
 2 = {HashMap$Node@4107} "javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource" -> 
 3 = {HashMap$Node@4108} "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" -> "${database.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}"
 4 = {HashMap$Node@4109} "javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" -> "ENABLE_SELECTIVE"
 5 = {HashMap$Node@4110} "hibernate.dialect" -> "${database.hibernate.dialect}"
 6 = {HashMap$Node@4111} "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" -> "${database.hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}"
 7 = {HashMap$Node@4112} "hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" -> "${database.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache}"
 8 = {HashMap$Node@4113} "hibernate.ejb.persistenceUnitName" -> "default"
 9 = {HashMap$Node@4114} "hibernate.connection.charSet" -> "${database.hibernate.connection.charSet}"
 10 = {HashMap$Node@4115} "hibernate.show_sql" -> "${database.hibernate.logSqlInfo}"
 11 = {HashMap$Node@4116} "hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" -> "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"
 12 = {HashMap$Node@4117} "hibernate.generate_statistics" -> "${database.hibernate.generate_statistics}"
 13 = {HashMap$Node@4118} "javax.persistence.validation.mode" -> "AUTO"
```

One can see that the properties are not expanded... Why is that?

Comment: Where does `application-test.properties` reside (e.g., `src/test/resources`)?

Comment: How are you executing the tests: Eclipse, IDEA, Maven, Gradle?

Comment: Hi Sam! `application-test.properties` is located in `src/main/resources` as well as `application.properties` that is not picked up by my spring boot tests either. I use `./gradlew integrationTest` with a custom integrationTest task.

Comment: Does it work if you run the test in the IDE?

Comment: No it does not work either. I have edited my post (see edit 2 above).

Comment: Any advice or help to debug this issue would be very welcome.

Comment: I have edited my post with relevant information.

Comment: `org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$ConfigurationPropertySources cannot be cast to org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileEnvironmentPostProcessor$ConfigurationPropertySources` is strange because there is no ConfigFileApplicationListener in spring-boot 1.3. Maybe you need to run a gradle clean.

Comment: Yes That's the error I got from the IDE. I don t get that from gradle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was actually with the following line of code:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {TestEnd2EndIntegrationConfiguration.class})
```

`TestEnd2EndIntegrationConfiguration` is not a Spring Boot Application with a main and most importantly it is not annotated with a `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation.

I changed to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        ...
        MailSenderAutoConfiguration.class
})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.bignibou.configuration", "com.bignibou.it.configuration"})
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and my abstract test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {TestApplication.class})//Notice the change
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(Profiles.TEST)
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

}
```

Now the tests run as a spring boot application and custom properties in `application.properties` are also resolved.

Comment: I assumed your `TestEnd2EndIntegrationConfiguration` class was annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. Sorry I didn't inquire in that regard, but I'm glad you figured it out! ;)

Comment: FYI: `TestApplication` does not need a `main` method. That's only necessary for launching the app from the command line.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the info. It actually makes more sense without the main!

Comment: @balteo, you do not need `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` for your integration tests, you can simply use `@ContextConfiguration` and specify all of your configuration classes like this: `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, SecurityConfig.class, MVCConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class})`

Answer (score 10):

You need 3 things to get your properties to be autowired in your integration test classes:

1. The `PropertySource` annotation. It looks like you're missing that.
   You can add something like this to your Abstract Integration Test class:

```
@PropertySource(value= {"classpath:*.properties"})
```

2. The property file must be in your classpath. I recommend adding a separate folder for test and integration test properties. Create an `integration-test-resources` directory within `src/main` and copy your property files into there, then configure your build manager to add them as classpath resources.

Here's an example how to do that in Gradle:

```
sourceSets {
  integrationTest {
     resources {
       srcDir "integration-test-resources"
     }
  }
}
```

3. Annotate your property with `@Value`. Looks like you are already doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should use `spring.jpa.hibernate.dll-auto` if you want to place your Hibernate properties in `application-${profile}.properties`, i.e. Spring properties file.

Likewise, `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` should be used.

I use Spring Boot with such configuration and I never had a need for any `@PropertySource` annotations.